# Get a byte[] from SendAsync using Rx.Net

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Effectively I am looking for that solution that can take given `IObservable<T>` can return/map that into an `IObservable<U>`

More specifically I want to go from `IObservable<HttpResponseMessage>` to `IObservable<byte[]>`

I know I can do this

```
byte[] bytes = await myHttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(...);
```

I am specifically not interested in that solution.

What I have So far:

```
IObservable<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return Observable.FromAsync(() => client.SendAsync(request));
}

IObservable<byte[]> DoWork()
{
    var request = new HttpWebRequest();
    // configure the request accordingly

    return SendRequest(request)
        // my quesiton is right here. Is this the proper way to do this?
        .SelectMany(x => x.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ToObservable());

    // To use Switch:
    // SendRequest(request)
    // .Select(x => x.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ToObservable())
    // .Switch();
    // ^ now that I see this, I think SelectMany is the right thing
    // since the web request will never emit more than 1 observable
    // and I just want to map/flatten one observable into another observable.
}
```

Coming from the Swift RX library, they have `flatMap` and `flatMapLatest`. It doesn't look like `SelectMany` returns an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` so adding `Switch` to line up with `flatMapLatest` seems out here. My guess then is that `flatMap` from swift rx = `SelectMany` in C# rx (System.Reactive)

**References**

https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/J.Van.Gogh/Reactive-Extensions-API-in-depth-SelectMany

http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html#Switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `map` is `Select` in .NET.
- `flatMap` is `SelectMany` in .NET.
- `flatMap`/`SelectMany` is equivalent to `map`/`Select` followed by `merge`/`Merge`.
- `flatMapLatest` is equivalent to `Select` followed by `Switch`.